# SQL ORDER BY behavior for other columns?

Tags: sql, database, position, sql-order-by

Column types chars.

```
COLUMN 1       COLUMN 2
   1x              A
   1x              B
   2x              A
   2x              B
   3x              A
   3x              B
```

ORDER BY COLUMN2 result:

```
COLUMN 1       COLUMN 2
   1x              A
   2x              A
   3x              A
   1x              B
   2x              B
   3x              B
```

With data of this form, it appears the first column is also sorted and is actually the outcome I'm looking for; (group by the sorted second column and within those, ordered by the first column)

First, is this behavior guaranteed?

Next, if so, what SQL spec sates this behavior?

Lastly, is this the proper way to achieve the desired outcome?

Thank You.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx) for the `ORDER BY` clause? It explains the behaviour when you sort by multiple columns and states that the order of rows returned is *not* guaranteed without `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @Pondlife: removed sql-server tag, not using that one specifically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not guaranteed. To guarantee it, you could do something like this:

```
select COL1, COL2 from YOURTABLE order by col2, col1
```

This tells your database to order it by COL2 first, and then if those are the same, further order it (break the tie, so to speak) by ordering on COL1. You can have as many of these as you want.

Comment: @Tommy Yes. I've updated my post to be more clear about that.

Comment: @TommYy: Yes. Try different combinations like `ORDER BY col2, col1 DESC` or `ORDER BY col2 DESC, col1` to see how it works.